# Samsung TV Video Caching using HTML5 and JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, fileapi, samsung-smart-tv

I have to develop a Samsung TV application to play videos that are served from  a remote server, which I don't have access to.

Actually I've made an application to play videos of my own server. But my current requirements are as follows:

1. I want to play videos that are served from a remote host (say //remote.com/video_id) to which I have no access, but my TV application is connected to my server (say //myserver.com/samsungapp)
2. I have to cache file on my Samsung TV before playing. ie., buffer 100% and then play

I've checked `FileApi` and `FileReader` using HTML5 and JS, and come up with following barriers:

Its difficult to send cross domain request from Javascript. Since I don't have access to remote host, I can't set `access-control-origin` on the remote server's response.

Any suggestions are appreciated...

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: @Phrogz I want to cache the video file somehow fully, before playing started

Comment: This may be of help: [Using Script tags to do remote HTTP calls in Javascript](http://jaybyjayfresh.com/2007/09/17/using-script-tags-to-do-remote-http-calls-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is method for modifying buffer size: [SetTotalBufferSize](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/Device_API/Player/SetTotalBufferSize)

But you can't buffer 100% of your video as it simply runs out RAM memory of the TV.

Therefore you have event to check if buffering is complete: [OnBufferingComplete](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/Device_API/Player/OnBufferingStartComplete_)

I don't know what is the purpose of your task, but you can download whole file to the device instead of buffering it.

Here is the method:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/SEF_Plugin_API/Download

So you can download movie and save it to the device. And after that play your movie from local.